# Yii2: Date saving default time '1970-01-01 00:00:00'

Tags: php, mysql, date, yii2

I have my validation rules setup like this:

```
[['service_start_time', 'service_end_time'],'default','value'=>Null],
[['service_start_time', 'service_end_time'],'date','format' => 'php:d-M-Y H:i a'],
```

and in function

```
public function beforeSave($insert) {

    $mytime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($this->date_time));
    $service_start_time= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($this->service_start_time));
    $service_end_time= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($this->service_end_time));

        $this->date_time = $mytime;
        $this->service_start_time = $service_start_time;
        $this->service_end_time = $service_end_time; 

        return parent::beforeSave($insert);

    }
```

Now why I am getting the date saved in the format `'1970-01-01 00:00:00'` when in the rule the `default` is setup as `Null`

Comment: What are the exact values of `$this->date_time`, `$this->service_start_time` and `$this->service_end_time`?

Comment: when I am trying to save the blank values I am getting this problem, otherwise it is working fine. on trying to save empty value, the value saved in the db is `'1970-01-01 00:00:00'`

Comment: @JohnConde- is there any solution for that?

Comment: I think you'll find that a date that is null is '1970-01-01 00:00:00'

Answer (score -1):

Please change date value format in service_time_start as Y-m-d instead of d-m-y..may it solve ur problem